# Merging DF in a list individually to another DF

Tags: r, dataframe, merge, lapply

I have a list of dataframes with varying dimensions filled with data and row/col names of Countries. I also have a "master" dataframe outside of this list that is blank with square dimensions of 189x189.

I wish to merge each dataframe inside the list individually on top of the "master" sheet perserving the square matrix dimensions. I have been able to achieve this individually using this code:

```
rownames(Trade) <- Trade$X
Trade <- Trade[, 2:length(Trade)]

Full[row.names(Trade), colnames(Trade)] <- Trade
```

With "Full" being my master sheet and "Trade" being an individual df.

I have attempted to create a function to apply this process to a list of dataframes but am unable to properly do this.

Function and code in question:

```
  DataMerge <- function(df) {

    rownames(df) <- df$Country
     Trade <- Trade[, 2:length(Trade)]
    
    Country[row.names(df), colnames(df)] <- df
  
  }
```

Applied using :

```
DataMergeDF <- lapply(TradeMatrixDF, DataMerge)
filenames <- paste0("Merged",names(DataMergeDF), ".csv")
mapply(write.csv, DataMergeDF, filenames)

Country <- read.csv("FullCountry.csv")
```

However what ends up happening is that the data does not end up merging properly / the dimensions are not preserved.

I asked a question pertaining to this issue a few days ago ([CSV generated from not matching to what I have in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68568511/csv-generated-from-not-matching-to-what-i-have-in-r)) , but I have a suspicion that I am running into this issue due to my use of "lapply". However, I am not 100% sure.

Comment: Do you have a matrix or data.frame.  Inside the function you have `Country` as the data, but outside there is `Full`, which one is correct

Comment: I would suggest to include a small reproducible example to test.

Comment: Also, I think your function should return the `Country` after the assignment i.e. `return(Country)}`

Comment: `Trade <- Trade[, 2:length(Trade)]` is redundant inside function unless you meant `df <- df[, 2:length(df)]`.

Comment: @Parfait I didn't notice that difference.  Thanks for mentioning it

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we return the 'Country' at the end it should work.  Also, better to pass the other data as an argument

```
DataMerge <- function(Country, df) {

    rownames(df) <- df$Country
     df <- df[, 2:length(df)]
    
    Country[row.names(df), colnames(df)] <- df
    Country
  
  }
```

then, we call the function as

```
DataMergeDF <- lapply(TradeMatrixDF, DataMerge, Country = Country)
```